# How to unit test a sphinx/docutils directive

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-sphinx, docutils

I have created a [Sphinx extension containing a directive](https://github.com/lnoor/sphinx-jsonschema/blob/master/sphinx-jsonschema/wide_format.py).

Now I want to include unit tests before I start to refactor it.
So using pytest I created a test file containing this fixture:

```
wide_format = __import__('sphinx-jsonschema.wide_format')

@pytest.fixture
def wideformat():
    state = Body(StateMachine(None, None))
    lineno = 1
    app = None

    return wide_format.WideFormat(state, lineno, app)
```

Which when used to create tests fails with errors complaining about the `None`s in the instantiation of the StateMachine.
I've tried to install some dummies, looked through docutil samples but can't find a working solution.

The problem is that `State` and `StateMachine` contain references to each other and I can't find a way to break that loop.

Answer (score 1):

Docutils directives are tested in [docutils/test/test_parser/test_rst/test_directives/](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/test/test_parsers/test_rst/test_directives/).
The main idea is to set up an rST parser and test it with rST input samples. A simple example is:

```
from docutils.frontend import get_default_settings
from docutils.parsers.rst import Parser
from docutils.utils import new_document

# setUp
parser = Parser()
settings = get_default_settings(Parser)  # required settings
settings.warning_stream = ''  # customize settings

# test data
source = '.. note:: this is an rST input sample'
expected = """\
<document source="test data">
    <note>
        <paragraph>
            this is an rST input sample
"""

# test case
document = new_document('test data', settings.copy())
parser.parse(source, document)
output = document.pformat()  # pseudoxml representation
assert output == expected
```